# subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector in c

Tags: c, arrays

how remove this error tried everything....
this program is about finding 5 closest number from a array...
in main part i simply take array, num and size and passes through the function

```
void printclosest(int arr[], int x, int n)
{
int diff[30];
int i,j,k,p,a;
 for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j)
        {
            if (arr[i] > arr[j])
            {
                a =  arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = a;
            }
        }
    }

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
diff[i]=abs(a[i]-x);

}


for (k = 0; k < n; ++k)
    {
        for (p = k + 1; p < n; ++p)
        {
            if (diff[k] > diff[p])
            {
                a =  arr[k];
                arr[k] = arr[p];
                arr[p] = a;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
  { printf("%d",arr[i]);
   }
    }
```

Comment: Please include the line number when posting the error!

Comment: Please give some more detail about what you expect to happen. And please format your code properly.

Comment: First of all, please format your code so it's readable.  Second of all, the compiler should be telling you what line the error is on.  What line is it?

Comment: @Martze You are given a sorted list of N numbers and a number Num. Write a program to find the five numbers that are closest (numerically) to Num. A number x in the array is closest to Num if |Num-x| is the smallest among all such x possible.

Note: If the Num is present in given list, then it should be in the output.

Answer (score 3):

`a` is declared as `int`, yet you try to use it as an array here:

```
diff[i]=abs(a[i]-x);
```

Comment: thanks buddy for help it compiled but i think my logic is incorrect i tried to get 5 closest numbers from array can you tell me where i went wrong

Comment: @avenger Post a new question, include the details and format the code. And read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You are given a sorted list of N numbers and a number Num. Write a program to find the five numbers that are closest (numerically) to Num. A number x in the array is closest to Num if |Num-x| is the smallest among all such x possible.

Comment: @2051 i don't have limit to post questions now plz help

Comment: @avenger Sorry about the time limit, you will simply have to wait.